# Как установить своё PhoneGap-приложение в iPhone без публикации в appStore и платного сертификата разработчика?

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap, apple

Имеется мобильное приложение разработанное на HTML5 (Framework7).
Тестировалось и проверялось в PhoneGap! Сборку готового приложения собираюсь делать через build.phonegap.com

Есть ли способ получить и установить данное приложение на свой iPhone (in-house) только для своих нужд без публикации в AppStore, без покупки сертификата Apple Developers, без jailbreak'а?

Comment: Jailbreak в помощь)) Айфон не андроид тебе))

Comment: т.е. без Jailbreak'а вообще никак? (((

Comment: Есть) Но это по моему это платно.. Apple provisioning profile должен открыть)

Comment: Нашел вроде бы решение: http://proswift.ru/zapusk-i-testirovanie-svoix-ios-prilozhenij-na-ustrojstve-bez-akkaunta-razrabotchika-i-bez-jailbreak/

Comment: Еще с выходом xcode7 эпл поменял правила - теперь вам не нужен платный аккаунт, чтоб записывать на девайс, только чтобы паблишить в аппстор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь попросить кого-то с аккаунтом сделать тебе appId и добавить твои девайсы в провижен. Раньше можно было найти такие объявления - за добавление просили всего несколько долларов.

Comment: а сертификат? его где взять тогда для создания приложения через https://build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: так владелец провижена его тебе тоже должен будет сбросить, вместе с провиженом.

Answer (score 1):

насколько я помню, если у вас есть .ipa, вы можете его перетянуть в itunes, и при подключенном девайсе, выбрать его из списка и нажать install. возможно, после этого надо будет сделать sync.

Comment: попробую Ваш вариант...

Comment: хотя о чём речь я же не могу получить установочный файл из build.phonegap.com из-за того что у меня нет сертификата разработчика Apple

Comment: @Enshtein сам такое не делал, но вроде в меню Run у вас должна быть опция Build Native App.

Comment: Это что за меню Run такое? В каком приложении? На https://build.phonegap.com такого нет

Comment: ну тогда видимо только если купить/отдолжить аккаунт